# vectorial ODE in mathematica with matrix exponentials

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

I want to solve the following equation in mathematica :

`DSolve[{X'[t] == A.X[t], X[0] == ( {{0},{0}} )}, X[t], t]`
It is a system of 2 ODEs coupled by the matrix A, that I don't want to put in the form `{{a,b},{c,d}}` in order to have the output as a function of matrix exponential.

Mathematica understands that but gives a solution strangely expressed as:

```
 {{X[t] -> 
 InverseFunction[Dot, 2, 2][A, 
     E^(t A.1)
     InverseFunction[InverseFunction[Dot, 2, 2], 2, 2][A, 0]]}}
```

Where it indeed uses a matrix exponential, but also relies on a strange notation `InverseFunction [...]`

My question is how to get rid of this `InverseFunction` notation to have a more readable expression. Do I for example have a manner to postulate that A is a (2,2) matrix, invertible, with inverse B?

Or more generally, how to solve vectorial ODE's and make Mathematica write the solution by relying on exponential matrix notation?

If I can hope a better result with maxima, please advise. Thanks a lot for help

Comment: *Mathematica* does not yet support symbolic, non-explicit matrices, so if you don't want to replace your `A` with something like `{{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}}`, there's not much you can do... still, look into `MatrixExp[]`.

Comment: @J.M. And that is a real pity :)

Comment: Thanks a lot JM. I tried that for this equation : `Y'=(A-B)Y+B*L`, and wrote it as : `DSolve[{{{Derivative[1][Y1][t]}, {Derivative[1][Y2][ t]}} == ({{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}} - {{b11, b12}, {b21, b22}}).{{Y1[t]}, {Y2[t]}} + {{b11, b12}, {b21, b22}}.{{L1}, {L2}}, {{Y1[0]}, {Y2[ 0]}} == {{L01}, {L02}}}, {{Y1[t]}, {Y2[t]}}, t]` But I got an error message : `DSolve::dsfun: "{Y1[t]} cannot be used as a function. "` , any idea?

Comment: Use `Thread` on your equations to get the `==` working on component level. You might need to throw in a `Flatten`.

Comment: I used Thread, `DSolve[{Thread[{{Derivative[1][Y1][t]}, {Derivative[1][Y2][
       t]}} == {{b11 L1 + 
       b12 L2 + (a11 - b11) Y1[t] + (a12 - b12) Y2[t]}, {b21 L1 + 
       b22 L2 + (a21 - b21) Y1[t] + (a22 - b22) Y2[t]}}], 
  Thread[{{Y1[0]}, {Y2[0]}} == {{L01}, {L02}}]}, {{Y1[t]}, {Y2[t]}},
  t]`but still have the same error message `DSolve::dsfun: "{Y1[t]} cannot be used as a function."`

Answer (score 4):

```
Module[{X, A, InitialCondition},
X[t_] = {X1[t], X2[t]};
InitialCondition = {0, 0};
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
Flatten@DSolve[{Thread[X'[t] == A.X[t]], Thread[X[0] == InitialCondition]}, 
X[t], t]]
```

Was what was meant by correct usage of `Thread` and `Level` I think. `{0,0}` is a trivial initial condition but with `{1,1}` you get:

```
Module[{X, A, InitialCondition},
X[t_] := {X1[t], X2[t]};
InitialCondition = {1, 1};
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
Flatten@DSolve[{Thread[X'[t] == A.X[t]], 
Thread[X[0] == InitialCondition]}, X[t], t] // FullSimplify]

{X1[t] -> (
  E^(1/2 (a + d) t) (Sqrt[4 b c + (a - d)^2]
   Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[4 b c + (a - d)^2] t] + (a + 2 b - d) Sinh[
   1/2 Sqrt[4 b c + (a - d)^2] t]))/Sqrt[4 b c + (a - d)^2], 
 X2[t] -> (
  E^(1/2 (a + d) t) (Sqrt[4 b c + (a - d)^2]
   Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[4 b c + (a - d)^2] t] + (-a + 2 c + d) Sinh[
   1/2 Sqrt[4 b c + (a - d)^2] t]))/Sqrt[4 b c + (a - d)^2]}
```

which is (as expected) the same as

```
MatrixExp[{{a, b}, {c, d}} t].{1, 1} // FullSimplify
```