# NDSolve fails to solve vector-valued function x'[t] == a . x[t] + u . b

Tags: differential-equations

I get no solution when I run the following command:

```
NDSolve[{
  x'[t] == 
    0. {{0}, {0}, {1.}} + {{0, 1., 0.}, {0, 0., 1.}, {0., -0.156816, -0.523512}} . x[t],
  x[0] == {0, 0, 0}}, 
  x, {t, 0, 1}]
```

The kernel just keeps running forever until I kill it. If I remove the `0. {{0}, {0}, {1.}}` term, then it works fine.

I'd appreciate your help with this issue.

Comment: Perhaps you can use this as a workaround: `psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == {a, b, c} + {{0, 1., 0.}, {0, 0., 1.}, {0., -0.156816, -0.523512}}.x[t], x[0] == {0, 0, 0}}, x, {t, 0, 1}, {a, b, c}]`; then `psol[1., 2., 3.][t]` or whatever vector you want instead of `{a, b, c} = {1., 2., 3.}`.  (`NDSolve` gets stuck processing the equation -- looks like it might be a bug.)  Wait and see if someone else knows....

Comment: I'll use your workaround. Thanks!

Comment: It works fine, if you put any non-zero term, like: `1.{1,2,3}`.

Comment: @m0nhawk To clarify, all the terms must be nonzero (at least for me).  I think that's why the workaround in my comment works - `{a, b, c}` are symbolic and not zero.

Answer (score 3):

This has been [addressed before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9070/vectorial-ode-in-mathematica-with-matrix-exponentials/9076#9076) and up to Mathematica 9 (I only have 10 at work at the moment and it's a hassle to switch computers) you couldn't handle symbolic, non-explicit matrices in the generic way you want to.

I suggest that if you are happy with the answer to that post you delete this as duplicate or if you are using mathematica 10 (which is probably the case since a non-zero term doesn't work in 9) you tag appropriately.

In any case, one way to handle systems of ODEs in `NDSolve` (in any version, I hope) is by writing the functions explicitly and making use of `Thread`:

```
sol = Flatten@Module[{X, A, B, initialCondition, coef},
    coef = 0;
    X[t_] = {X1[t], X2[t], X3[t]};
    initialCondition = {0, 0, 0};
    A = {{0, 1., 0.}, {0, 0., 1.}, {0., -0.156816, -0.523512}};
    B = coef {0, 0, 1};
    NDSolve[{
      Thread[X'[t] == A.X[t] + B],
      Thread[X[0] == initialCondition]
      },
     X[t],
     {t, 0, 1}
     ]
    ];
```

Now as @m_goldberg points out, you get a trivial solution with `coef=0` but for non-zero values you get a non-trivial solution. You can check the dependence of your equations by setting `coef` as a parameter to `ParametricNDSolve`

```
sol2 = Flatten@Module[{X, A, B, initialCondition},
    X[t_] = {X1[t], X2[t], X3[t]};
    initialCondition = {0, 0, 0};
    A = {{0, 1., 0.}, {0, 0., 1.}, {0., -0.156816, -0.523512}};
    B = coef {0, 0, 1};
    ParametricNDSolve[
     {
      Thread[X'[t] == A.X[t] + B],
      Thread[X[0] == initialCondition]
      },
     X[t],
     {t, 0, 1},
     coef
     ]
    ];
```

and now you can look at the variation of your solutions with non-zero coefficients:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Through[({X1[t], X2[t], X3[t]} /. sol2)[i]],
  {t, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {-.5, .5}],
 {i, -2, 2}]
```

[image: manipulate of solutions vs coef]

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that with `coef = 0` the differential equation in question yields the trivial solution `X[t_] = {0, 0, 0}`. Non-zero values of `coef` give non-trivial solutions.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that the equations evaluate to ones with inconsistent dimensions, because `Plus` threads the components of the constant vector/list term with the unevaluated `Dot` product.  Since `NDSolve` is not `HoldAll` or `HoldFirst`, what the equation evaluates to is relevant. (V9.0.1 actually issues a warning about inconsistent dimensions).

```
{x'[t] == 0. {{0}, {0}, {1.}} + {{0, 1., 0.}, {0, 0., 1.}, {0., -0.156816, -0.523512}}.x[t],
 x[0] == {0, 0, 0}}
(*
  {Derivative[1][x][t] ==
    {{0. + {{0, 1., 0.}, {0, 0., 1.}, {0., -0.156816, -0.523512}}.x[t]},
     {0. + {{0, 1., 0.}, {0, 0., 1.}, {0., -0.156816, -0.523512}}.x[t]},
     {0. + {{0, 1., 0.}, {0, 0., 1.}, {0., -0.156816, -0.523512}}.x[t]}},
   x[0] == {0, 0, 0}}
*)
```

If `x'[t]` is a 3-vector, then the dimensions of the RHS work out to `{3, 1, 3}`.  And if the constant term is changed to a more consistent-looking `0. {0, 0, 1}`, the dimensions of the RHS are `{3, 3}`.  *For some reason, if all of the components of the constant term are nonzero, in V10 `NDSolve` processes the equation "correctly", that is, as intended.*  If one or more of the components are zero, then either the kernel runs forever or it crashes in V10; in V9 an error is issued.  (I'm not sure why it works for nonzero components.)

The following system evaluates to consistent dimensions and works in V10/V9.  Using a variable `b[t]` in place of the list keeps `Plus` from threading the components of `b[t]` prematurely.

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{
   x'[t] == b[t] + {{0, 1., 0.}, {0, 0., 1.}, {0., -0.156816, -0.523512}}.x[t],
   x[0] == {0., 0., 0.},
   b[0] == 0. {0., 0., 1.}},
  x, {t, 0, 1}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> {b}]
```

Comment: I didn't know that worked in 9 (you answered while I was editing)! +1 from me.

Comment: @gpap Thanks! I might have addressed a similar problem in a similar way before, but I haven't found it yet.